# changing div's using jquery problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have this click function `note` when clicked it should change a couple of css values using jquery, here goes:

```
$('a.note').click(function(){
     $('#leftpanel').css('border-left-width', '20px');
      $('#commentbox').css('visibility', 'hidden');
     $('.date').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

html:

```
<div id="leftpanel>blahbalhbalh number 1</div>
<div id="leftpanel>blahbalhbalh number 2</div>
```

but the jquery only chnages the css of the first `leftpanel` div, and not the second one, how can i resolve this or is thier a problem, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` should be unique per element per page, that's your problem, you should do:

```
<div id="leftpanel">blahbalhbalh number 1</div>
<div id="leftpanel2">blahbalhbalh number 2</div>
```

Or you can use same `class` instead if you want:

```
<div class="leftpanel">blahbalhbalh number 1</div>
<div class="leftpanel">blahbalhbalh number 2</div>
```

And then you can use jQuery to target via class as well.

Comment: but that changes the design of the second one, i have css properties on the div leftpanel, not left panel2 thanks

Comment: @getaway: You can style the leftpanel2 similarly like leftpanel via different id (ids can never be same for more than one element) or you can use a class if both have the similar styling.

Comment: can i ask you a question, if i wanted to put the values for i.e border-left width in a hidden field i.e `$('#inputcss').val(x); what value shall i put in x :))

Comment: You can put value of whatever element you like eg `$('#inputcss').val($('#leftpanel').css('border-left-width'));`